# Question about definition of diagonalizability

Tags: linear-algebra

> Definitions: a linear operator T on a finite-dimensional vector space V is called diagonalizable if there is an ordered basis $\beta$ for V such that $[T]_\beta$ is a diagonal matrix.

I am confused with the term 'diagonalizable', can someone give me an example to understand the definition? Any reference or help is appreciated.

Comment: Where are you confused? Do you know what a diagonal matrix is? Do you know what it means to represent a linear operator as a matrix with respect to some basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $\beta=(b_1,b_2,\dots, b_n)$. Then the $i$th column of $[T]_\beta$ (by definition) consists of the coordinates of $T(b_i)$ when written as a linear combination of $b_1,\dots, b_n$.

This matrix is diagonal if and only if the coefficient of $b_j$ in $T(b_i)$ is $0$ for $j\ne i$, that is, if for each $i$, we have $T(b_i) =\lambda_ib_i$ for some scalar $\lambda_i$. This can be also said as each $b_i$ is an *eigenvector*.

For a specific example, consider the reflection $S$ through $x=y$ in the plane. It simply switches the standard basis vectors, and in that basis its matrix is 
$$[S] =\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$$
Now, $S$ fixes the axis $u:=\pmatrix{1\\1}$, and inverts its perpendicular $v:=\pmatrix{-1\\1}$, i.e. we have 
$$S(u)=u,\ \quad\ S(v) =-v$$
and thus in the basis $\gamma:=(u,v)$ its matrix is diagonal:
$$[S]_\gamma =\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}\,.$$